# Loading data in SwipeRefreshLayout with help of Baseadapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, swiperefreshlayout

```
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.adapter.DemoAdapter.getView(DemoAdapter.java:78)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1320)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:324)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 09:20:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 09:22:37.049: E/Trace(1806): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

What I am doing in I am loading some data in SwipeRefreshLayout with the help of BaseAdapter. Complete code is as follows.

This is the main activity class.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.activity;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.R;
    import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.adapter.DemoAdapter;
    import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.gettersetter.GetterSetter;
    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseFile;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,OnRefreshListener{
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
        Bitmap VideoThumbImage = null;
        ListView VideolistView;
        DemoAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<GetterSetter> newArray = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
        ArrayList<GetterSetter> newArray2 = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
        public List<ParseObject> objectTest;
        int initialnum = 0;
        int finalnum = 5;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            swipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(MainActivity.this);
            setContentView(swipeRefreshLayout);
            VideolistView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> newQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Videos");
            newQuery.whereExists("url");
            newQuery.addDescendingOrder("number");
            newQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (e == null) {
                        int dataSize = list.size();
                        for (int i = initialnum; i < finalnum; i++) {
                            ParseFile Youtubeimage = (ParseFile) list.get(i).get(
                                    "VideoImage");
                            byte[] imageconvert;
                            try {
                                imageconvert = Youtubeimage.getData();
                                VideoThumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                                        imageconvert, 0, imageconvert.length);

                            } catch (ParseException ee) {
                                ee.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String Title = (String) list.get(i).get("Title");
                            String urlYou = (String) list.get(i).get("url");
                            GetterSetter setItNow = new GetterSetter();
                            setItNow.setImage(VideoThumbImage);
                            setItNow.setTitle(Title);
                            setItNow.setUrl(urlYou);
                            newArray.add(setItNow);
                        }
                        adapter = new DemoAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                                newArray);
                        VideolistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        VideolistView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                        objectTest = list;
                        initialnum = finalnum;
                        if((list.size()-finalnum)>5){
                            finalnum = finalnum+5;
                        } else {
                            finalnum = list.size() - finalnum;
                        }

                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Log.d("THis is ", "7");
            Log.d("This is Testing", "Testing");
    //      Log.d("The size is", "This is the size :- "+objectTest.size());

            swipeRefreshLayout.addView(VideolistView);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    SystemClock.sleep(2000);

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This is the object Length :- "+objectTest.size() +", This is the ini :- "+initialnum+", This si the final num" + finalnum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (int i = initialnum; i < finalnum; i++) {
                                ParseFile Youtubeimage = (ParseFile) objectTest.get(i).get(
                                        "VideoImage");
                                byte[] imageconvert;
                                try {
                                    imageconvert = Youtubeimage.getData();
                                    VideoThumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                                            imageconvert, 0, imageconvert.length);

                                } catch (ParseException ee) {
                                    ee.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String Title = (String) objectTest.get(i).get("Title");
                                String urlYou = (String) objectTest.get(i).get("url");
                                GetterSetter setItNow2 = new GetterSetter();
                                setItNow2.setImage(VideoThumbImage);
                                setItNow2.setTitle(Title);
                                setItNow2.setUrl(urlYou);
                                newArray2.add(setItNow2);
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is the size of the new Array :- " + newArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            adapter.DemoAdapter2(MainActivity.this, newArray2);
                    //      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    //                      VideolistView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    });
                };
            }.start();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

This is the Adapter class

DemoAdapter.java

```
    package com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.adapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Binder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.R;
    import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.gettersetter.GetterSetter;
    import com.parse.RefreshCallback;

    public class DemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context cont;

        ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter;
        ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter2;
        LayoutInflater inflate;

        public DemoAdapter(Context cont,ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter){
            this.cont = cont;
            this.refrehsetter = refrehsetter;
        }

        public void DemoAdapter2(Context cont,ArrayList<GetterSetter> newrefrehsetter) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cont = cont;
            refrehsetter2 = newrefrehsetter;
            this.refrehsetter.addAll(refrehsetter2);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(cont, "This is the size after call :- "+refrehsetter2.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //      refrehsetter.addAll(refrehsetter2);
    //      notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public class Holder{
            ImageView image;
            TextView url, Title;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Holder hold = null;
            inflate = (LayoutInflater) cont.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(ConvertView == null){
                ConvertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.layout_trailer_item, null);
                hold = new Holder();
                hold.image = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                hold.Title = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                hold.url = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.urlID);
                Toast.makeText(cont,"This is not the result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                hold = (Holder) ConvertView.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(cont,"<<<<<This is the result>>>>>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            GetterSetter getset = (GetterSetter) getItem(position);
            hold.image.setImageBitmap(getset.getImage());
            hold.Title.setText(getset.getTitle());
            hold.url.setText(getset.getUrl());
            return ConvertView; 
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return refrehsetter.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return refrehsetter.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return refrehsetter.indexOf(getItem(arg0));
        }
    }
```

This Below is the Getter Setter.

GetterSetter.java

```
    package com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.gettersetter;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;

    public class GetterSetter {
    String url;
    Bitmap image;
    String title;
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    }

Here I am trying to load the data on refresh but when I swipe to refresh It is not loading the new data that I have got. Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong.
```

Comment: I think you need to set setRefreshing() to "true" in your baseadapter. Right now it set to "false" in onRefresh() & because it's not getting true. Thatswhy its not refreshing contents/loading new contents.

Comment: I appreciate your help but setRefreshing() is used for setting the animation status. When it is set to false it means that at that point the animation that is displayed at the top of the listview will stop.

Comment: You can check that whether list is refreshing using isRefresh(). With the help of it you can get idea whether its refreshing or not.

Comment: Let me add one of the error... Editing the question again.

Comment: what is line number 78 in adapter class?

Comment: This is line 78 "return refrehsetter.size();"

Comment: I guess there is becoming mismatch of count. One more thing is print size of arraylist

Comment: Still I dont think refrehsetter.size(); is line number 78. There is problem in your getView(). Check it once again. Because its showing nullpointerexception in your getView()

Comment: I printed the size of the array list in the "public void DemoAdapter2(Context cont,ArrayList<GetterSetter> newrefrehsetter)"

after the addall() method and it gives me updated list. and its getting added.

Comment: What is the size of that arraylist?

Comment: Yes RIT there's the problem I have been trying and left no stones unturned(which logically is incorrect as I dont have solutions) but I dont know whats the error. Look when I run the program and refresh it then if you see there is a line in getview() which is as follows 

GetterSetter getset = (GetterSetter) getItem(position);

After this line the program stops at this line and doesnt forwards to the next line as shown below which is in getview().

hold.image.setImageBitmap(getset.getImage());

Comment: Old size of arraylist was 5 and on adding it new arraylist size is 10

Comment: I got it where is the problem. Let me explain

Comment: ok please RIT I will be really thankful to you my dear :)

Comment: See the thing is in your onRefresh(), you are setting newArray2 but unfortunately its not getting updated in your custom adapter. Call this.refrehsetter.addAll(refrehsetter2); this in your 1st DemoAdapter() constructor. The problem was yur are accessing refreshsetter in getView but you are not adding it. Just add it in 1st DemoAdapter() constructor, it'll surely solve your problem.

Comment: ok RIT I am doing it for surely but till that time can you also provide a code snipped of the thing I should update. In case that I don't get it right. But yes I am trying you can count on that.

Comment: Try to do it, read my last comment, it'll help you to understand & solving problem. & I'm here only, just let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: See you are telling me to add this.refrehsetter.addAll(refrehsetter2) in my constructor but refrehsetter2 is getting initialized when I am calling onRefresh(); Also I did tried to add it to the constructor like this given below :- 

 public DemoAdapter(Context cont,ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter){
  this.cont = cont;
  this.refrehsetter = refrehsetter;
  this.refrehsetter.addAll(refrehsetter2);

 }

But it gives force close when running and not even loads the data for the first time.

Comment: Man you need to add validation for that.

Comment: Add this in your 1st DemoAdapter constructor : if(refreshsetter2.size > 0)
  {
   //do ur stuffs
  }

Comment: You mean like this  "ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter2 = null;" ?? because that too doesnt work.

Comment: Check my last comment

Comment: Hey dear toooooooo confused can you provide me the constructor code. Because I had given it so much time that I am not able to think anything :(. I have been trying this since yesterday..

Comment: Ok let me try one more time. And thanks for your time RIT :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey all there was the error in handling the adapter tag. I wan not setting the Tag and also I was not setting the layout inflator in the proper place. Let me post the Adapter class.

```
package com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.R;
import com.example.swiperefreshdemoprac.gettersetter.GetterSetter;

public class DemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context cont;

    ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter;
    LayoutInflater inflate;

    public DemoAdapter(Context cont,ArrayList<GetterSetter> refrehsetter){
        this.cont = cont;
        this.refrehsetter = refrehsetter;
        inflate = (LayoutInflater) cont.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void updateNewArray(ArrayList<GetterSetter> setit){
    //  refrehsetter.clear();
        refrehsetter.addAll(setit);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView url, Title;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder hold;
        View view = ConvertView;
        if(ConvertView == null){
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.layout_trailer_item, null);
            hold = new Holder();
            hold.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            hold.Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            hold.url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.urlID);

            view.setTag(hold);

            Toast.makeText(cont,"This is not the result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            hold = (Holder) ConvertView.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(cont,"<<<<<This is the result>>>>>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        GetterSetter getset = (GetterSetter) getItem(position);
        hold.image.setImageBitmap(getset.getImage());
        hold.Title.setText(getset.getTitle());
        hold.url.setText(getset.getUrl());
        return view;    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return refrehsetter.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return refrehsetter.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return refrehsetter.indexOf(getItem(arg0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting more data ? or you're getting updated data ?

If you're "refreshing" your list, then you shouldn't add the new list to your old list, you should just set your data source in the adapter to be the new refreshed list.

If you're getting more data, `addAll()` method will cause new data to be added at the bottom of your list.

Comment: What I actually want to do is add a new data along with the old data. And I want to get more data when I refresh. I had used addall() but it is not working I dont know why.

Comment: Are you sure your thread in onRefresh() is actually getting more data ?

Comment: Yes it is getting the data onRefresh(); I actually checked whether I am getting the data and I printed it in the log and its working. But I dont know how to bind that data with the existing listview.